# Can't use *.pfx certificate on the server but can while local testing

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a `cert.pfx` file which contains a certificate and a private key.

I use this line of code to access it

```cs
var x509 = new X509Certificate2("cert.pfx", "the password", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

On my local machine it works and I can even run

```cs
Console.WriteLine("{0}Subject: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.Subject);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Issuer: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.Issuer);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Version: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.Version);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Valid Date: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.NotBefore);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Expiry Date: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.NotAfter);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Thumbprint: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.Thumbprint);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Serial Number: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.SerialNumber);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Friendly Name: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.PublicKey.Oid.FriendlyName);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Public Key Format: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.PublicKey.EncodedKeyValue.Format(true));
Console.WriteLine("{0}Raw Data Length: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.RawData.Length);
Console.WriteLine("{0}Certificate to string: {1}{0}", Environment.NewLine, x509.ToString(true));
```

and get the correct output but as soon I run the code in a console app on a Windows Server 2012 R2 I get the following error

> The specified network password is not correct.

The password I use is definitely correct as I can use this command

```
openssl pkcs12 -in cert.pfx -nocerts -out key.key
```

to extract the key.

Any idea what the Problem might be?

Comment: Do you have special characters in your password? You can try to show in a messagebox your passwor to be sure that when you read the file you get the exact password on the server.

Comment: @CoskunOzogul that was also my first guess but it was the same (woudl have be strange otherwise, because it literally just copied the bin folder to the server). But thanks nonetheless :)

Comment: The password is the private key that was used to generate the certificate.  The error message says "Network Password" which is not the certificate password.  You do not have the permissions to access the certificate in the certificate stores.

Comment: @jdweng how can I not have the permission? On my local machine I do run the program from a normal powershell promt and on the server I run it from and admin powershell promt as an admin? How can I get more permissions to use the .pfx file?

Comment: A network credential may not the same as you local machine credential.  The local and remote machines has to be in the same group.  Windows is secure so data passed between two machines are encrypted and uses a key that is generated for the group.  Then you have to user account on both local and remote machine that are linked.

Comment: @jdweng but I access the server over remote connection and login as a local admin user. Shouldn't this user have all permissions?

Comment: Not necessarily.  You can have a different local admin on local machine and remote machine.  The same account has to be used on both local and remote machine.  Just because the account name is the same does mean the account is linked between the two machines.

Comment: @jdweng okay, then I will talk to the sys-admins about this problem and hope that they can solve the issue.